# Marker view not showing with MPChartAndroid library

Tags: java, android, charts, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am facing an issue where I am building a custom marker but the marker does not appear. This is my code from the char activity. Could it be that the problem is from the `getEntryForIndex(index).icon`?

**This is my main activity**

```
 class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity(), OnChartValueSelectedListener {


    lateinit var dataSet : LineDataSet

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        /**
         * Get the first year value from the API and to the logic here for each here
         */
        var fistYearValue = 9
        var secondYearValue = 10
        var thirdYearValue = 11
        var fourthYearValue = 12
        var fifthYearValue = 13
        var sixthYearValue = 14
        var sevenearValue = 15
        var eigthYearValue = 16


        val numArr = intArrayOf(fistYearValue, secondYearValue, thirdYearValue, fourthYearValue, fifthYearValue,
            sixthYearValue,sevenearValue,eigthYearValue)

        val numMap = HashMap<Int, Any>()

        /**
         * TODO get current year and increment by 8
         */
        numMap[fistYearValue] = "2018"
        numMap[secondYearValue] = "2019"
        numMap[thirdYearValue] = "2020"
        numMap[fourthYearValue] = "2021"
        numMap[fifthYearValue] = "2022"
        numMap[sixthYearValue] = "2023"
        numMap[sevenearValue] = "2024"
        numMap[eigthYearValue] = "2025"
        val entries1 = ArrayList<Entry>()


        /**
         * Define xAxix variable
         */
        var xAxis = linechart.xAxis


        /**
         * Configure xAxix
         */
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
        xAxis.axisLineColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM

        linechart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this)



        for (num in numArr)
        {
            entries1.add(Entry(num.toFloat(), num.toFloat()))
        }
        dataSet = LineDataSet(entries1, "Numbers")


        /**
         * Configure data set
         */
        dataSet.setDrawFilled(true)
        val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.chart_background)
        dataSet.fillDrawable = drawable


        /**
         * Hide grid layout
         */
        linechart.axisLeft.setDrawGridLines(false)
        linechart.axisRight.setDrawGridLines(false)
        linechart.isHighlightPerTapEnabled = true
        linechart.axisRight.setDrawLabels(false)
        linechart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
        linechart.axisLeft.setDrawLabels(false)
        linechart.axisLeft.isEnabled = false
        linechart.legend.isEnabled = false
        linechart.description.text = ""


        //dataSet.getEntryForIndex(0).icon = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_group_7)
        /**
         * Zooming and pinching functions
         */
        linechart.setScaleEnabled(false)
        linechart.setPinchZoom(false)


        linechart.setDrawMarkers(true)
        dataSet.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false)
        dataSet.highLightColor = Color.parseColor("#4e4e4e")
        dataSet.color = Color.BLACK
        dataSet.setDrawCircles(false)
        dataSet.setDrawValues(false)


        val data = LineData(dataSet)
        xAxis = linechart.xAxis
        xAxis.valueFormatter = IAxisValueFormatter { value, axis -> numMap.get(value.toInt()).toString() }
        linechart.data = data
        linechart.invalidate()

    }


    override fun onNothingSelected() {}

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry?, h: Highlight?) {

        var previousIndex  = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)
            .getInt("INDEX", 0)

        dataSet.getEntryForIndex(previousIndex).icon = null


        //save current position
        var index = dataSet.getEntryIndex(e)
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext).edit()
            .putInt("INDEX", index).apply()

        //set current position
        dataSet.getEntryForIndex(index).icon = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_group_7)
        var x = linechart.xAxis.valueFormatter.getFormattedValue(e?.x!!, linechart.xAxis)
        var y = linechart.xAxis.valueFormatter.getFormattedValue(e.y, linechart.xAxis)

        var mv =  MyMarkerView(this, R.layout.marker)
        mv.chartView = linechart

    }

    inner class MyMarkerView(context: Context, layoutResource: Int) : MarkerView(context, layoutResource) {

        private val tvContent: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvContent)


        override fun refreshContent(e: Entry?, highlight: Highlight?) {
            tvContent.text = "3"
        }

        override fun getX(): Float {
            return (-(width / 2)).toFloat()
        }


        override fun getY(): Float {
            return (-height).toFloat()
        }

    }
}
```

**This is my marker.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvContent"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please remove the Java tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. I solved passing the `activity` to my `MyMarkerView` instance, passing the `super.contentRefresh()` in my `MyMarkerView` and then I made a few changes in the `xml`.

So: 
`pieChart.setMarker(new MyMarkerView(MyActivity.this, R.layout.marker_chart_popup));`

`MyMarkerView` code:
public class MyMarkerView extends MarkerView {

```
    private TextView tvContent;

    public MyMarkerView (Context context, int layoutResource) {
        super(context, layoutResource);

        tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
    }

    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
        tvContent.setText("my value " + e.getY()));             
        super.refreshContent(e, highlight); // <----- IMPORTANT

    }

}
```

and my custom layout `marker_chart_popup`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:minWidth="60dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="test"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I worked for me, i hope it helps you.